# How to fix cadvisor error `devicemapper filesystem stats will not be reported`?

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I am running the official cadvisor Docker image `google/cadvisor:v0.24.1` according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor#quick-start-running-cadvisor-in-a-docker-container) (only replaced the tag with the current version instead of `latest`):

```
docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:v0.24.1
```

Looking at the logs inside the container, I see this:

```
W0318 17:50:00.775708       1 fs.go:209] Could not get Docker devicemapper device: exit status 1
E0318 17:50:00.840177       1 factory.go:291] devicemapper filesystem stats will not be reported: stat /dev/mapper/dockervg-dockerlv_tmeta: no such file or directory
```

The docker command mounts the root filesystem of the host under `/rootfs` inside the container. Isn't cadvisor supposed to access the dm devices there?

I found no setting I could change pointing cadvisor to the real rootfs.

Do I have to mount /dev/mapper into the container at /dev/mapper?

---

Yes, I'm using devicemapper:

```
$ docker info -f '{{ .Driver }}'
devicemapper
```

It's just that inside the container, `/dev/mapper` only has one file:

```
$ docker exec cadvisor  ls /dev/mapper -l
total 0
crw-------    1 root     root       10, 236 Mar 18 17:50 control
```

The real `/dev/mapper` directory of the host is accessible inside the container at `/rootfs/dev/mapper` but cadvisor just does not use it...

---

After some BMHATK looking through the source code, I think this use case is just not supported by cadvisor, cf. https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/utils/docker/docker.go#L64

```
metadataDevice = fmt.Sprintf("/dev/mapper/%s_tmeta", poolName)
```

So it always looks for the device in `/dev` instead of `/rootfs`.  Also, the next version disables the thin_ls watcherr by default due to excessive iops.  So, I might simply live without it.

Comment: Are you using devicemapper? Include the output of `docker info -f '{{ .Driver }}'`

Comment: Also, what are you using for your docker host. Debian, Ubuntu, RHEL, CentOS, D4W, D4M, or a cloud provider?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7.

Comment: Would you also include the `docker run` command you used? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for CentOS include additional parameters (privileged and mapping the /cgroup volume) needed in your `docker run` command:

```
docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  --privileged=true \
  --volume=/cgroup:/cgroup:ro \
  google/cadvisor:v0.24.1
```

See [these instructions](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/running.md#centos-fedora-and-rhel) for more details.

Comment: Yes, it says so in the docs, but I do not use SELinux so I thought I would not need this. I have tried it now and it does not work, unfortunately. Same error shows up in the logs. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Looks like `--privileged` isn't including the symbolic links in the devices folder for me, you can directly mount the directory in as a volume to get around that with `-v /dev/mapper:/dev/mapper`